# Wrong matching using regexp in cypher queries

Tags: regex, neo4j, cypher

I use the [Cineasts Movies & Actors (12.3MB) dataset](http://www.neo4j.org/develop/example_data), and I want to get the path from Kevin Bacon and all the US actors he has played with, who have also played in a Drama film. So I've made this cypher query, which returns no row:

```
START KB=node(759)

MATCH (KB)-->(m1)<--(p)-->(m2)

WHERE HAS(p.birthplace) AND p.birthplace =~ ".*(USA|United States)" AND m2.genre = "Drama"

RETURN m1, p, m2
```

However if I get rid off the regexp (`p.birthplace = "USA"`), it returns one result. What is wrong? The initial query should return at least one row. I'm using Neo4j 1.9.2.

Comment: You should also use relationship-types like `(KB)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m1)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(p)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m2)` and try to not use node-id's but rather index-lookups to find nodes.

Answer (score 2):

Actually this is more REGEX than neo4j or cypher.
Your are missing parantheses. (USA|United States) Means USAnited States OR USUnited States, bc the | is ORing the two Characters A and U. Try ((USA)|(United States))

EDIT:
PS, try this site for some great regex support and tests http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: I tried but it is not working. It is working only if I remove `AND m2.genre = "Drama"`, which is really weird.